# MonoGame - Error 9009 & IgnoreMe.dll not found

Tags: c#, .net, monogame

i've just installed MonoGame and XNA and i'm having some issues from the jump, from googling it seems as though i need to add 'C:\Windows\System32' to my path environment variables, i've tried adding it here

[image]

but i'm still getting these errors

Error   1

> The command "SETX MONOGAME_PLATFORM "PSM" > NUL" exited with code 9009.    MyMonoGameContent

Error   2

> Metadata file 'C:\Users\Benji\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\myMonoGame\MyMonoGameContent\MyMonoGameContent\bin\PSM\IgnoreMe.dll' could not be found    C:\Users\Benji\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\myMonoGame\myMonoGame\CSC  myMonoGame

This happens when i try to compile after referencing my content project

[image]

i'm following these http://rbwhitaker.wikidot.com/monogame-tutorials

no idea what's up, was that the wrong place to set the enviroment variable? i've tried looking for a user property sheet but can't find one in my project

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't expect that you would want to create content for the PSM (PlayStation Mobile).  Check the targeted platform of the ContentBuilder project to ensure you are building for Windows.